# What methods to contain in an abstract?

Tags: writing-style, abstract

It is my first time writing an abstract for an assignment and I am wondering if I need to include all of the methods used within a piece of research. I understand I don't need to include every tiny detail of the procedures, however say if the research has multiple methods used, e.g five different individual types of psychological tests administered to a participant and only three of them yield significant results, should I include them all? Should I instead only include ones that I report in the results section of the abstract i.e significant findings. Many thanks.

Comment: Usually when requested to write an abstract there are parameters like word limits, section titles, etc. if this assignment did not include parameters then it is left to your discretion. You can find published manuscripts in your subject area for examples. Once you read a few you should have a good idea of what to do. Typically, I describe the results the most and would suggest describing the methods that are unique the most and summarizing the steps that are not. Focus on novelty, results and implications. Keep the intro short and sweet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good abstract provides brief information about the article and does not hide anything. The goal is to attract other scientists who are searching the literature to read the article. And here it is necessary to state that even information about methods that did not bring results is desirable information. So you can put it in the abstract. However, if the names of the methods are too long, then only listing those that have produced results, would be sufficient.